# How to modified json in Bot Framework Channel Emulator

Tags: json, botframework

I need to try a Bot Framework Channel Emulator
for use to post data to my api Controller
but my struc of json in my program is not like a json from this emu
How can i do? or i should create self script for test send json same propertie of my program.

thank.

[botframework ui (this json i want to modified)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3WoQ.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information about why your are trying to do this?   What are you trying to change and why?

Comment: I need to try use this app post data to my controller,I have my own api and try to find something to post data to my app.And my app it have different properties in json object.

Comment: I think it could be useful, to try to micmic other channels like facebook id's and stuff instead of the random generated from id.